# Adding a table column calculating ratio based on the values in other columns in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table in ssrs 2008 like

```
Name      Date:[Date]
[Name]    [Amount]
```

Example output:

```
Name      Date:2015-04-01   Date:2016-04-01
John             50               100
Jack             150              135
Mike             250              250
```

The column including `[Amount]` information has a column group based on `Date`.
What I want is to add another column showing the `Change Ratio` like:

```
Name      Date:2015-04-01   Date:2016-04-01   ChangeRatio
John             50               100             100%
Jack             150              135             -10%
Mike             250              250             0%
```

I am looking for a way to provide it on the rdl, without modifying the Stored Procedure in SQL. How can i perform it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column outside right, called change ratio, set its format to percent.

Find the name of the date column and use this in the expression for change ratio via reportitems!. Attached is breakdown how i have mananged to complete this.[image]